# Thread safe container for queue

Tags: c++, vector

I have an application where I deal with sockets. In this application, I REALLY NEED to run send() to the same socket, from several different threads.
To avoid errors or messing with the sent data, I want to create a kind of queue.
For this queue, I need a container that will store the data.

I thought of using something like std::vector, where a thread will check at all times if there is any data in it, and if there is, it will send one item at a time, and remove each item after sending.
The items would be added to this std::vector when it was necessary to send something to the socket, through the push_back function.

The problem is that I don't know how to do this safely, avoiding errors of any kind, as the std::vector would MOST LIKELY be accessed at the same time by different threads, whether to add, read or remove items.

If there's a better way to do this that isn't like what I'm talking about or doesn't use std::vector, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Stop obsessing about the containers. None of them are thread-safe. Instead, encapsulate the container and build a thread-safe interface around it using `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`. There's no need to poll it. Just make your "add" routine signal the condition variable. Make your "pop" routine block on that condition. Use the `mutex` to protect the container. The consumer thread(s) will wake up and safely consume data only when it becomes available.

Comment: In general if documentation does NOT explicitly state a datastructure is threadsafe, then it is NOT. To make a threadsafe queue, you will need. 1. a queue, 2. a mutex, 3. a condition variable to notify something has been queued. 4. a wait method that waits until something has been queued and return the first item of the queue (and pop it).

Comment: There are also many third-party implementations of thread-safe data structures, especially queues. They are usually called _concurrent_. These may be in some situations more efficient than not-thread-safe data structures protected by a mutex. I would suggest looking at the solutions provided, e.g., by oneTBB, Boost, and Folly libraries.

Comment: @paddy: Do you suppose it might be a little premature to presume they're "obsessing" when this is literally the first question they've ever posted?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Wrong choice of words! I really just meant to say "worrying".

Comment: @paddy: I agree--that would certainly have been a better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, building a queue is one of the rare times that you're probably justified using a container other than `vector`. `std::deque` is probably the most obvious choice, since it actually *is* a queue (with a couple extra things you don't care about for now).

Since you want to access it (and in particular, write to it) from multiple threads, you *need* do protect access to it. Multiple threads writing concurrently will give undefined behavior.

Anthony Williams has published the source for a pretty [solidly written concurrent queue](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).

There are a few changes I prefer. First of all, I think the `empty` member function he provides is basically useless--almost any use of it is subject to race conditions (i.e., by the time you try to decide something based on what it's returned, that may have changed).

He also provides two `pop` functions:

- `try_pop`: pops something immediately, or fails
- `wait_and_pop` waits (indefinitely) for something to be present, then pops it

Personally, I prefer a `pop` that allows you to specify a timeout, and always returns a Boolean to indicate success/failure. If you specify a timeout of 0, it's equivalent to his `try_pop`. If you specify a long timeout, you can get pretty much the behavior of his `wait_and_pop`. But, importantly, you can also specify times in between those two extremes, which is often quite useful. I usually end up using a timeout somewhere in the range of 100 ms to 1 second or so.

For example, you'll probably have a thread that pops an item from the queue, and sends it out the socket. But you also want to be able to exit cleanly from that thread, so you want it to check its stop token once in a while, and exit clean if the stop token is set. So you end up with a loop something like this:

```cpp
while (!stop_token) {
    if (the_queue.pop(item, timeout)) {
        socket.send(item);
    }
}
```

A timeout around the 0.1 to 1.0 second range balances prompt exit when asked to do so with minimal CPU usage to poll the stop token when it would otherwise be sitting idle.

Of course, that's not the only way to do things, but I find that it works well in practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::mutex` to prevent data race, and `std::condition_variable` for signaling threads.

```
auto cv = std::condition_variable{};
auto vt = std::vector<Message>{}; // You could use queue instead
auto mtx = std::mutex{};

void consume() {
    while (true) {
        auto msg = Message{};
        {
            auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{mtx};
            while (vt.empty()) {
                cv.wait(lock);
            }

            msg = vt.back();
            vt.pop_back();
        }
        // Do something
    }
}

void produce() {
    // Do something
    {
        auto lock = std::scoped_lock{mtx};
        vt.push_back(msg);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

Your container should be protected by mutex using RAII.

Condition variables are synchronization primitives that enable threads to wait until a particular condition occurs.